# Referring to userform by name to add items to ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'd like to create a generic procedure for populating ComboBox lists in different UserForms. The lists are saved in an excel sheet shLists. The procedure is to find the correct list by name and then fill it with elements. Unfortunately I don't know how to reference the control to add items.

Below is my attempt, which unfortunately ends with a Type Mismatch error. How to do it properly?

```
Sub ReadComboBox(FrmName As String, CtrlName As String, ListName As String)

Dim Succes As Boolean
Dim W As Integer, K As Integer

With shLists
   K = 1
   Succes = False
   'Finding right column to read data
   Do While .Cells(1, K) <> ""
      If LCase(ListName) = LCase(.Cells(1, K)) Then
         Succes = True
         Exit Do
      End If
      K = K + 1
   Loop
   'If right name not found - inform and stop
   If Not Succes Then
      MsgBox "Dla ComboBox " & Kontrolka & " nie odnaleziono nazwy listy " & NazwaListy
      Stop
   End If
   W = 2
   'Adding items to the list
   Do While .Cells(W, K) <> ""
      UserForms(FrmName).Controls(CtrlName).AddItem .Cells(W, K) 'This generates "type mismatch" error
      W = W + 1
   Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just pass the control itself as an object?

Comment: No, no reason :) Just had no idea it is possible. Thanks!

Comment: try .`FrmName.CtrlName.AddItem .Cells(W, K).Value `

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but it will not work. I am going to use this macro for many UserForms and controls. Hardcoded names are not a solution in this case.

Comment: Say, in sheet shLists, cell A1 value "FRUIT" - A2:A4 value is Banana, Orange, Apple, cell B1 "COLOR" - B2:B4 value : Red, Green, Blue.....  IF the sub is called within `UserForm_Initialize`, as @Rory suggested, maybe try like this `Sub PopulateCombo(ctrl As Object, ListName As String)`. Then `With Sheets("shLists"):Set rgList = .Columns(.Rows(1).Find(ListName, lookat:=xlWhole).Column).SpecialCells(xlConstants):Set rgList = rgList.Resize(rgList.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0):end with` then `ctrl.List = Application.Transpose(rgList.Value):end sub`.

Comment: In UserForm_Initialize `Call PopulateCombo(Me.ComboBox1, "color")` ---> it create rgList from B2:B4 of shLists. Then it populate the ctrl by transposing the rgList value. `Call PopulateCombo(Me.ComboBox1, "fruit")` this will populate the ctrl from the fruit list (A2:A4 of shLists).

Comment: @Rory - please post an answer. Your comment solved the problem. So we can mark it as solved.